# KVO not working for custom property of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-observing, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I have a subclass of NSManagedObject `Folder` with a state of `Availability`

```
@objc enum Availability: Int16 {
  case unknown
  case available
  case unavailable
}
```

Folder has to do extra stuff (like delete related files) whenever it's availability changes. So I have

1. `internalAvailability` saved in core data
2. Computed property `availability` using above property

`

```
extension Folder {
  @NSManaged private var internalAvailability: Availability
}

extension Folder {
  private func deleteFiles(...) {
  ...
  }

  @objc dynamic public var availability: Availability {
    get {
      return internalAvailability
    }
    set {
      willChangeValue(forKey: "availability")
      deleteFiles()
      internalAvailability = newValue
      didChangeValue(forKey: "availability")
    }
  }
}
```

Using Reactive, I want to change navigation item's title based on availability but the signal is never called after once!

```

```
let property = DynamicProperty<NSNumber>(object: folder, keyPath: "availability")
internalVariable = property // To have a reference of property

navigationItem.reactive.title <~ property.map { (stateNumber) -> String in
  guard let a = Availability(rawValue: stateNumber.int16Value) else {
      assertionFailure()
      return ""
  }
  let prefix = a == .available ? "" : "(Nope) "
  return "\(prefix)\(folder.name)"
}
```

I have explicitly added KVO compliance to the property in hopes that this starts working, but alas no results.

Edit: if I create the `DynamicProperty` on `internalAvailability` instead of `availability`, everything works smoothly..

Comment: I think your problem is not with KVO, it is with ReactiveSwift and ARC, the `<~` infix operator returns a `Disposable`,  try to take a reference to this disposable like you did with `internalVariable = property`, this will keep this Disposable alive.

Comment: That didn't work. :(
Extra information: if I create the `DynamicProperty` on `internalAvailability` instead of `availability`, everything works smoothly.

Comment: I’m not familiar with ReactiveSwift, but is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) relevant?

Comment: Have you tried observing the property with normal KVO? That should allow us to figure out if the issue is with the KVO implementation or the ReactiveSwift portion.

Comment: Yes I tried that, normal KVO also didn't work.

Comment: I think @pbasdf might be right. Have you tried implementing `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`?

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf, I initially was trying to work with `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, but for some reason swift wasn't ready to accept that with a valid `super` call. cc: thanks @jjoelson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer since it became a learning exercise. Hopefully someone else too would be benefitted.

The app uses a multiple managedObjectContext(moc) architecture. 1 private moc to make changes and 1 main thread moc that synchronises itself using [mergeChanges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506546-mergechanges).

In above code, `navigationItem` is using the folder instance kept with main-moc. The DynamicProperty is listening to KVO changes on this main-moc's folder instance. Let's call this main-folder. When I make changes, I modify the folder instance we have on private-moc. Let's call it private-folder.

On modifying private-folder and calling `save` on private-moc, a notification of name `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` is broadcasted. main-moc synchronizes itself using mergeChanges.

**mergeChanges changes main-folder, but notice that it would never call the computed-property-setter `availability`. It directly changes `internalAvailability`.**

And thus, no KVO notifications are posted of our computed property.

**TL;DR** When doing KVO on a NSManagedObject subclass, use a stored property instead of computed one. In case you have a multi-moc (managed object context) scenario and use [mergeChanges](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506546-mergechanges) to synchronise, setter for your computed property is not called when synchronising.

**Edit (Solution):** add method of the pattern `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<KeyName>` [KVO relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html)

```
@objc class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingAvailability() -> Set<NSObject> {
  return [#keyPath(Folder.internalAvailability) as NSObject]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Core Data we use the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification instead of KVO. This brings many advantages including coalescing of change events and undo support. If we need to know what attributes changed on an object we can examine `changedValuesForCurrentEvent` which even includes transient attributes that have a matching `keyPathsForValuesAffecting...`. These advantages likely outweigh those from a KVO binding framework aka reactive.

Comment: Can you share documentation of `NSManagedObjectsDidChange`, or did you mean `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`.
Also, if you read the answer carefully, parent-child relationship is not used in the two MOCs. They have no relationship altogether.

Comment: I fixed those 2 mistakes, thanks for letting me know